# When using databasedotcom ruby gem to access salesforce, how do I get the ActivityHistory for a particular User (or Account)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, salesforce, databasedotcom-gem

For most sobjects, they support queries such as find_by_... etc. However,

```
client.materialize("ActivityHistory")
```

returns a class that does not support query.
When I try to run ActivityHistory.query("anything")

I get...

Databasedotcom::SalesForceError: entity type ActivityHistory does not support query

I'm trying to extract the ActivityHistory for the last 30 days, and find out the account it lies in, and the user that created it.

Help, please!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, putting it here for future reference.

Unfortunately the ActivtyHistory table is not directly accessible, it has to be queried through a relationship e.g. Account. For more info.. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8327/accessing-email-sent-in-activity-history-via-api